# Custom validator in zend framework 2

Tags: php, validation, zend-framework, zend-framework2

I am new to Zend framework. I'm using custom validators to validate image file but I'm getting this error.

```
Zend\Validator\ValidatorPluginManager::get was unable to fetch or create an instance for ImageValidator
```

Here is validation file:

```
namespace User\Validator;

//use User\Validator\FileValidatorInterface;
use Zend\Validator\File\Extension;
use Zend\File\Transfer\Adapter\Http;
use Zend\Validator\File\FilesSize;
use Zend\Filter\File\Rename;
use Zend\Validator\File\MimeType;
use Zend\Validator\AbstractValidator;

class ImageValidator extends AbstractValidator
{  
    const FILE_EXTENSION_ERROR  = 'invalidFileExtention';
    const FILE_NAME_ERROR       = 'invalidFileName'; 
    const FILE_INVALID          = 'invalidFile'; 
    const FALSE_EXTENSION       = 'fileExtensionFalse';
    const NOT_FOUND             = 'fileExtensionNotFound';
    const TOO_BIG               = 'fileFilesSizeTooBig';
    const TOO_SMALL             = 'fileFilesSizeTooSmall';
    const NOT_READABLE          = 'fileFilesSizeNotReadable';

    public $minSize = 64;               //KB
    public $maxSize = 1024;             //KB
    public $overwrite = true;
    public $newFileName = null;
    public $uploadPath = './data/';
    public $extensions = array('jpg', 'png', 'gif', 'jpeg');
    public $mimeTypes = array(
            'image/gif',
            'image/jpg',
            'image/png',
    );

    protected $messageTemplates = array(   
            self::FILE_EXTENSION_ERROR  => "File extension is not correct", 
            self::FILE_NAME_ERROR       => "File name is not correct",  
            self::FILE_INVALID          => "File is not valid", 
            self::FALSE_EXTENSION       => "File has an incorrect extension",
            self::NOT_FOUND             => "File is not readable or does not exist", 
            self::TOO_BIG               => "All files in sum should have a maximum size of '%max%' but '%size%' were detected",
            self::TOO_SMALL             => "All files in sum should have a minimum size of '%min%' but '%size%' were detected",
            self::NOT_READABLE          => "One or more files can not be read", 
    );

    protected $fileAdapter;

    protected $validators;

    protected $filters;

    public function __construct($options)
    {
        $this->fileAdapter = new Http();  
        parent::__construct($options);
    }

    public function isValid($fileInput)
    {   
        //validation code
    } 

}
```

and here is form file:

```
namespace User\Form;

use Zend\Form\Form;
use Zend\InputFilter\InputFilter;
use Zend\Session\Container;
use User\Validator\ImageValidator;

class PlatFormForm extends Form
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct('platform-form');
        $this->addInputFilter();
        $this->setAttribute('method', 'post'); 
        $this->setAttribute('enctype','multipart/form-data');
        $this->setAttribute('class', 'platform_popup');

        $this->addElements(); 
    }

    private function addElements() 
    {
        $this->add([
                'type'  => 'file',
                'name' => 'input_thumb',
                'attributes' => [                
                    'id' => 'input_thumb', 'class' => 'upload'
                ]               
            ]);

        $this->add([
                'type'  => 'submit',
                'name' => 'submit',
                'attributes' => [                
                    'id' => 'add_platform', 'class' => 'upload'
                ],
                'options' => [
                    'label' => 'CREATE',
                    //'label_attributes' => [

                    //],
                ],              
            ]);
    }   

    private function addInputFilter() 
    {
        $inputFilter = new InputFilter();        
        $this->setInputFilter($inputFilter);

        $inputFilter->add([
            'name'     => 'input_thumb',
            'required' => true,
            'filters'  => [
               ['name' => 'StringTrim'],
               ['name' => 'StripTags'],
            ],                
            'validators' => [
               [
                'name' => 'ImageValidator',
                  'options' => [
                    'minSize' => '64',
                    'maxSize' => '1024',
                    'newFileName' => 'newFileName2',
                    'uploadPath' => './data/'
                  ],
               ],              
            ],
          ]
        );      


    }  
}
```

and here is module.config.php file code:

```
'validators' => array(
        'invokables' => array(
            'ImageValidator' => 'User\Validator\ImageValidator' 
         ),
    ),
```

Can anyone suggest me what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To inject the validator options into your constructor method you should register your validator like this inside your `module.config.php` file:

```
<?php
use Zend\ServiceManager\Factory\InvokableFactory;
use User\Validator\ImageValidator;

return array(

    //...

    'validators' => array(
        'factories' => array(
            ImageValidator::class => InvokableFactory::class 
        ),
        'aliases' => array(
            'ImageValidator' => ImageValidator::class
        )
    ),

    //...

);
```

Comment: :) Thanks for reply. Can you suggest me how to get new uploaded file name in controller action? I'm using validation rule like.. 'validators' => [
      [
    'name' => '\User\Validator\ImageValidator',
      'options' => [
     'minSize' => '1',
     'maxSize' => '1024',
     'newFileName' => time() . 'newFileName2',
     'uploadPath' => getcwd() . '/public/uploads/platform/'
      ],
      ],      
   ],           
and it's working properly but I have no idea to how to get file name or error in controller action.

Comment: @anil You are welcome. That should be considered a new question. I suggest you accept my answer and ask a new question on StackOverflow if you cannot find an existing one that deals with this renaming issue already. You could also check out the docs that I refer to in another related answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37469717/1697459).

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I ran into the same problem, and first of all you don't need to inject anything ( unless you want to ). Just by adding the full path to the Validator will work, in your example:

```
private function addInputFilter() 
    {
        $inputFilter = new InputFilter();        
        $this->setInputFilter($inputFilter);

        $inputFilter->add([
            'name'     => 'input_thumb',
            'required' => true,
            'filters'  => [
               ['name' => 'StringTrim'],
               ['name' => 'StripTags'],
            ],                
            'validators' => [
               [
                'name' =>'User\Validator\ImageValidator\ImageValidator',
                  'options' => [
                    'minSize' => '64',
                    'maxSize' => '1024',
                    'newFileName' => 'newFileName2',
                    'uploadPath' => './data/'
                  ],
               ],              
            ],
          ]
        );      
    }
```

But I would like to point out that this is not the correct way of uploading files, regardless if they are images or not. You need to use **FileInput()** instead.

The simple example can be found here: https://framework.zend.com/manual/2.4/en/modules/zend.input-filter.file-input.html